# Packages cannot be nested and syntax error inporting packages in FLASH

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am new to flash and I am fallowing tutorial in book and aster creating new package as .as script when I try importing it I get 2 errors I am not sure what is wrong !
Errors are :

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 2   1093: Syntax error.
Untitled-1\Star.as, Line 1  1037: Packages cannot be nested.
```

First of all the project code part what gives error :

```
import flash.display.Shape;
#include "Star.as"; //syntax error here ?

var rect:Shape = new Shape(); 
rect.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x0000FF); 
rect.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); 
rect.graphics.drawRect(25, 25, 50, 50); 
addChild(rect);
rect.x = rect.y =  50;
```

The package is like this :

```
    package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.display.Shape;

    public class Star extends Shape {
        private var n:int; //spokes
        private var r:Number; //radius
        private var c:uint; //color
        private var t:Number; //line thick

        public function Star(n:int = 6, r:Number = 40, col:uint = 0x0000FF, t:Number = 1){
            //constructor
            super();
            this.n = n;
            this.r = r;
            this.c = col;
            this.t = t;
            graphics.lineStyle(t, c);
            var a:Number = 2*Math.PI/n; //leņķis
            var p1, p2:Point;
            for(var i:int = 0; i < n; i++){
                p1 = Point.polar(r, i*a);
                p2 = Point.polar(r, i*a+Math.PI);
                Graphics.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
                Graphics.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
                graphics.lineStyle(4*t, 0x000000);
                graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong....
if I delete that #include line it works ok just without package.

Package is creating simple well and should be right..
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

To import a class to your project, you should use [`import`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#import) and not [`include`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#include), so your code can be like this :

```
import Star;

var star:Star = new Star();
    addChild(star);
```

In your `Star`class, `Graphics` should be `graphics`.

Hope that can help.